# Getting the Links of a page in background of the page and displaying in main page

Tags: iframe, hyperlink, web-crawler

is it possible to load a webpage(example:webpage2) in background(example: www.Google.com) and get the content of the webpage2  in the main page ?

scenario: I wanted to get the link in the **webpage2** and display in the main page.